# Function looping in Column and Cumulative Value R

Tags: r, loops, csv, row, cumulative-sum

I have hundreds `.csv` files consists of year and HS information which looks like this:

```
      Year   HS
   1  1956  3.2
   2  1957  4.1
   3  1958  3.6
   .. .... ....
```

I need to to calculate each value in HS column using specific formula (to get another value), and find the cumulative value of them. After that, I've to write all the cumulative value in 1 `csv` file. So, basically I need to loop between files, and between rows in a column in the file.

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work. All data in `a` show "NULL".

```
    temp <- Sys.glob("out*")
pr<- lapply(temp, read.table, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
a<- lapply (pr, function(x) for (j in 1:57)
       cumsum(57-j*x[j,3]/3190))
prv<-do.call(rbind,a)
write.csv(prv,file="par.csv")
```

It looks like my data in column selection `x[j,3]` didn't work. Is there any suggestion for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it be easier to combine all the files into one and then compute said formula using `mutate()`?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to explore about `mutate` function first. However, I don't really think that I can combine all files into one dataframe. unless I want to divide them later since each file represent a specific coordinate.